# How to add shared libraries to my jar by gradle 2.2.1?

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, android-gradle-plugin

I have some external shared libraries to be added one jar file. The file structure as following:

```
project
|---lib
  |---armeabi-v7a/xxx.so
  |---x86/xxx.so
|---libs
  |---xxx.jar
  |---xxx.jar
```

My build.gradle is:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir 'src/main/java'
            }
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['lib']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}

task makeJar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
    into('../../releases/')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename ('classes.jar', 'myjar.jar')
}
makeJar.dependsOn(clearJar, build)
```

I use the command to view jar:

```
$ jar tf myjar.jar
...
armeabi-v7a/
armeabi-v7a/xxx.so
x86/
x86/xxx.so
```

But it will cause the crash by:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load xxx from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader

**How to properly do it ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your jar path to dependencies like this:

```
dependencies { 
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile files(‘libs/***.jar')
}
```

---- Edit ----

And

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jni.srcDirs = [] // disable automatic ndk-build call
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs'] // add your jni .so file path
    }
}
```

Comment: No. The jar file can be found at runtime, but so can't. The problem is shared libraries don't locate in the right folder, so system cannot find them.

Answer (score 0):

Restructure the file structure:

```
project
|---lib
  |---lib
    |---armeabi-v7a/xxx.so
    |---x86/xxx.so
|---libs
  |---xxx.jar
  |---xxx.jar
```

The build.gradle like this:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/main/java'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/../lib'
        }
    }
}
task makeJar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
    into('../../releases/')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename ('classes.jar', 'myjar.jar')
}
```